# How do I add one model objects to another model’s ModelForm template with many to one relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a Hospital Management System in which have Two ModelForms, one ModelForm creates Patient Object, And another form of model two is used to admit that Patient which means it uses Patient Objects in New Form Template with new fields and creates new ID Which have model one id(patient ID) and model two id(IPD ID )as well and model two is linked with model one with Patient Id,one patient can have multiple Ipd id
models.py :

```py
class Patient(models.Model): 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20);
    address = models.TextField();
    patient_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True);
    gender= models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=10)
    consultant = models.CharField(choices=CONSULTANT, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class Ipd(models.Model):

    reason_admission = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    presenting_complaints = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    ipd_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    date_of_admission = models.DateField(("Date"),
        default=datetime.date.today)  
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, default = "")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name
```

forms.py :

```py
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['name','phone','address','patient_id','consultant','Gender']

class IpdForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ipd

        fields = ['patient', 'reason_admission', 'presenting_complaints', 

                'rooms', 'date_of_admission']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(IpdForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['patient']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Patient.objects.all())
```

views.py:

```py
@login_required
def show(request, patient_id):
    patient = Patient.objects.filter(pk=patient_id)
    return render(request, 'show.html', {'patient': patient})

@login_required
def new(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = PatientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.save():
                return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Patient is successfully created.', 'alert-success'))
            else:
                return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
        else:
            return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        form = PatientForm()
        return render(request, 'new.html', {'form':form})

@login_required
def edit(request, patient_id):

    if request.POST:
        patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=patient_id)
        form = PatientForm(request.POST, instance=patient)

        if form.is_valid():

            if form.save():
                return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Patient is successfully updated.', 'alert-success'))
            else:
                return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
        else:
            return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        form = PatientForm(instance=patient)
        return render(request, 'edit.html', {'form':form})



@login_required
def ipd(request, patient_id):
    object = get_object_or_404(Ipd, patient__patient_id=patient_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)
        if formtwo.is_valid():
            instance = formtwo.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse(formtwo.errors) 
    else:
        formtwo = IpdForm()

    return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'object': object, 'form2': formtwo})
```

urls.py :

```
url(r'^order/ipd/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.ipd, name='ipd'),
```

html :

```
{% for field in form2.visible_fields %}
<div class="card-panel">                                                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Name : {{name}}</span> <br>                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Phone : {{ phone  }}</span><br>                                                  
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Address : {{ address  }}</span> 
<br>                                                                                         
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Gender : {{ gender  }}</span><br>                                            
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please share some code and maybe your expected result

Comment: @Iain Shelvington I have updated my code, I want Patient Objects In My Ipd Form Template to create Ipd(admit) of that patient,So when I apply for Ipd of the Specific Patient I get data of the patient and some new Fields in my Ipd Form Templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add modelchoicefield for patient model in the init function of IPD ModelForm like below

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(IpdForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['patient']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Patient.objects.all())
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to represent that in templates

Comment: you can show the form altogether as {{form2}} in the template  or you can show each field as {% for field in form2.visible_fields  %}<p>field.label</p><p>field</p> something like this

Comment: sorry sir! Still not working , I have updated code,  when i am creating loops , multiple blank template "card-panel"     are appearing

Comment: Shall I add certain queryset in views ?

Comment: nope, just make sure that there is records in db for patient model